# load jquery and bootstrap and pass google speed test mobile version

Tags: jquery

Trying to load jquery and bootstrap and pass mobile version. Google is saying: *Your page requires additional network round trips to render the above-the-fold content. For best performance, reduce the amount of HTML needed to render above-the-fold content.*
I tried compressing all content and images.  Gzip compression tests show the server is sending my files Gzip compressed. Now I'm not sure if there any thing extra i could be coding into the .htaccess file to receive those files better. I tried defer and async on js files. I even gone as far to put bootstrap and jquery files inline. Which improved my score but still falling short of passing. I scoured the internet. Is there anything else i can do or am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found a major issue with my .htaccess file that gave me a passing score! But still have to go through all the things i did above to pass googles speed test mobile version. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Thx I tried all that too. I read a lot on speed modules. Is it worth investing the time going down that road?

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve load times is to load your external libraries, such as jQuery and Bootstrap, from external CDNs (content delivery networks). These CDNs are cached and mirrored around the world so no matter where the user is, the load time should be minimal. Additionally, if the user has already loaded the library from that CDN, it may have the script cached locally which means it won't have to load anything at all.

Next, instead of using the entire Bootstrap library, you can create a custom version of it that has anything you're not using stripped out of it. For example, if you can strip out all the buttons and form styles if you're only using their grid system. Likewise, you don't need to load the Bootstrap javascript if you're not using dropdown menus, modals, etc.

Finally, make sure you're using minified versions of all your scripts and stylesheets. There is a significant savings between a library with comments and spacing compared to its minified counterpart.

Comment: Thx I tried all that too. I read a lot on speed modules. Is it worth investing the time going down that road?

Comment: You should always optimize your content. Minifying your js and css is the same as compressing your images.